# How to replace particular sub component from the main component using Navigator in react native

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, react-native

In my scenario `<MainComponent />` having so many subcomponents .But particular subcomponent i need to populate the new data with all other subcomponents.

```
var MainComponent =  React.createClass({ 
     renderScene:function(route, navigator) {

         var type=this.props.type;
         if(type =="text"){
            <GetInputField/>
          }
         else if(type=="number"){
            <GetNumberField/>
         }
         else if(type=="image"){
            <GetImageField />

     //using this <GetImageField> component i am showing two buttons.
     //while click on the button i moving to another scene .
     //in this scene i am showing local images using CameraRoll component.
    // When select the image i need to populate that image in the <GetImageField/> component  through the navigator.
    // But i am unable to replace to the <GetImageField/> component using navigator
         }

     },

      render:function() {
          return(<Navigator
               renderScene={this.renderScene.bind(this)}
               navigator={this.props.navigator}
               navigationBar={
                 <Navigator.NavigationBar style={styles.navBarStyle}
                     routeMapper={NavigationBarRouteMapperDisplayCustomSchema} />
               } />)
     }

 })
```

In my scenario i need to populate the images in `<GetImageField />` component with other components of `<MainComponent/>`

Answer (score 0):

If the `CameraRoll` is a child of `GetImageField` you can just pass a callback property. For instance:

```
var GetImageField = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return <CameraContainer onPhotoSelected={this.updatePhotos} />
  },

  updatePhotos: function(images) {
    this.setState({ images });
  }
});
```

If it's not a children then you might need to use events to propagate the information over.

Might be worth reading this [overview of how React components can communicate](https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/communicate-between-components.html).